# FFMPEG Video loop from images files

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a video from a bundle of image files and then apply a an overlay on top of it.Another requirement is to make the video loop 3x. It is simply not working.
The requirement is to produce a video of 3 seconds looped 3x. The below script does npt allow to do it.

This is my script.

```
ffmpeg 
-start_number 1 -framerate 3/1 
-i "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\963d9d9b8e1\DSC%04d_0013.jpg"

-"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\xxx\xxx\projects\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\963d9d9b8e1\DSC%04d_0013.jpg"

-i "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\xxx\xxx\projects\1237\1138\pictures\bundle\963d9d9b8e1\DSC%04d_0013.jpg"

-i "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\xxx\xxx\projects\1237\1138\overlay.png" 
-i "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\xxx\xxx\projects\1237\1138\overlay.png" 
-i "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\xxx\xxx\projects\1237\1138\overlay.png" 
-filter_complex " [0:v]scale=600x900[scaled1]; [1:v]scale=600x900[scaled2]; [2:v]scale=600x900[scaled3]; [scaled1][3:v]overlay[tmp1]; [scaled2][4:v]overlay[tmp2]; [scaled3][5:v]overlay[tmp3]; [tmp1][tmp2][tmp3]concat=n=3[scaled] "
-map [scaled] -r 10 -vcodec libx264  -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23  "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Projets\2020\xxx\video test ffmpeg\test.mp4"
```

Comment: Please specify in details what means your sentence “It is simply not working.”

Comment: Original question was also answered at the crosspost at Stack Overflow: [FFMPEG Video loop from images files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60441262/1109017), but the quesiton requirements changed after answering.

Answer (score 1):

The "solution" that you gave to your own question confuses me because it seems to be somewhat unrelated to your initial question.

What I understood from your question:

1. You have a Sequence of Images in 3 directories.
2. Make a movie from each Image Sequence.
3. Length is 1s each.
4. Overlay an image for each 1s movie.
5. concatenate the movies -> 3s movie
6. Loop 3 times -> 9s movie

I've added the fllowing to your code in your question:

1. Add `-start_number 1` before every input
2. Add `loop=loop=2:size=30` after `concat`

Notice `loop=2` loops 3 times.

Furthermore it needs a size (the total number of frames to loop over).

This depends on how many images you had.

I had 10 images in the 3 directories. `10 x 3 = 30`

```
ffmpeg \
-start_number 1 -framerate 12 \
-i "imgSequ1/img-%d.png" \
-start_number 1 -framerate 12 \
-i "imgSequ2/img-%d.png" \
-start_number 1 -framerate 12 \
-i "imgSequ3/img-%d.png" \
-i "overlay1.png" \
-i "overlay2.png" \
-i "overlay3.png" \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]scale=600x900[scaled1];\
[1:v]scale=600x900[scaled2];\
[2:v]scale=600x900[scaled3];\
[scaled1][3:v]overlay[tmp1];\
[scaled2][4:v]overlay[tmp2];\
[scaled3][5:v]overlay[tmp3];\
[tmp1][tmp2][tmp3]concat=n=3,loop=loop=2:size=30[scaled]" \
-map "[scaled]" -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 "result.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution and it works.

-start_number 1 -framerate 3/1 
-i DSC%04d_0013.jpg 
-loop 1 -i overlay.png"
-filter_complex "
[0:v]scale=600x900[scaled];
[scaled][1:v]overlay,trim=duration=3,loop=loop=2:size=9[tmp]
" -map [tmp] -r 10 -vcodec libx264  -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 
test.mp4